# Encryption Decryption in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, encryption

I'm trying to use encryption and decryption in Perl on Linux, I can see modules like mime::base64 and rc4.

I have tried base64 and rc4 but it didn't work   properly, any suggestions would be really helpful.

Like I want to encrypt initially after some operation i want to decrypt it.

Comment: Don't use RC4 nowadays. Use authenticated encryption such as AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305 for example through libsodium.

Comment: "but it didn't work properly" - that's a terrible description of your problem. Exactly what unexpected behaviour did you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIME::Base64 is not encryption, but encoding. Look at for instance [Crypt::CBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::CBC) for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

base64 is an encoding module that is used by some as diy code obfuscation technique.

Consider using `Crypt::RSA` and `Crypt::SaltedHash` for your purposes.